# Python Extract the matching JSON Value from Array

Tags: python, arrays, json

Im calling an API that gives the output in an array. This is the array data.

```
["{'meta':'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574'}","{'del':'projects/us/conf/001a1143e726'}"]
```

Here I want to extract the value for the key meta.

#### Expected output:

```
projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574
```

How can I do this with Python? Also, the output is in correct array structure?

Comment: Are you asking how to use dicts and lists?

Comment: Im new to Python concepts, not sure its dicts or list. Basically something like `print(array(meta))` Please check the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix would be to convert data[0] to a dict using json.loads -

```
value = json.loads(d[0].replace('\'','"'))['meta']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean get the value where the key is meta you can use `next` and a comprehension:

```
data = ["{'meta':'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574'}","{'del':'projects/us/conf/001a1143e726'}"]
```

---

```
>>> next(v for (k, v) in map(dict.items, data) if k == 'meta')
projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is array is loaded into the variable `data`, `data[0]` is the dictionary with one key `'meta'`. From there, you can access that key by passing the name.

```
>>> data = [{'meta':'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574'}, {'del':'projects/us/conf/001a1143e726'}]
>>> data[0]['meta']
'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574'
```

Comment: thats a big assumption based on OP ... i would take him at his word about the weird return ... seems like a bug with the api though

Answer (score 0):

if your input is really looking like that (bad api design, or a bug in the API)

you can just load each as json

```
fixed = [json.loads(string_thing.replace("'",'"')) for string_thing in response_array]

 >>> fixed[0]['meta']
 u'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574'
 >>> fixed[1]['del']
 u'projects/us/conf/001a1143e726'
```

if you wanted to make it one big dict

```
data = {}
for string_thing in response_array:
    # this assumes the strings are valid json and always dicts
    data.update(json.loads(string_thing.replace("'",'"')))

>>> data
{u'meta': u'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574', u'del': u'projects/us/conf/001a1143e726'}
>>> data['meta']
u'projects/us/conf/94eb2c1f0574'
>>> data['del']
u'projects/us/conf/001a1143e726'
```